# Logo and images not shown in gmail accounts magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, email-templates

I getting issue about for displaying images and logo in gmail account when i send email to customers through magento2 then logo and images are not shown why because of the reason I search a lot to find out the solution still not getting anything to resolved for it, please help me out of this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sending mails from local or live server?

Comment: From local environment if you are sending email then you can not able to see images there in gmail

Comment: sending mails via server

Comment: Do images use https?

Comment: no its only http://

Comment: Is your email available in spam ?

Comment: Not in spam, it is in inbox,

Comment: Can you please inspect element there in gmail and try to run Image's URL in your browser ? and can you please check are you able to run that or you're getting any errors ?

Comment: yes tried getting 404 That’s an error.

Comment: check by creating new customer and then create order with that customer.

Comment: yes tried but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Configuration here

> Store > Configuration > Advance > Developer > Static Files Settings > Sign Static Files

Here you can select **No** and then clear your Magento cache.

- If versioning is enable there at that time Magento set URL with `version13213213` like this. So when we deploy site at that time Google first find image in caching and that may be creates an issue. If you'll disable versioning then that will work properly.

Hope this solution will work for you!

Comment: Did you tried this ?

Comment: yes its already set No Sign Static Files

Comment: Can you please share your Gmail logo's URL with me ? If possible ?

Comment: here is gmail ss : https://nimb.ws/z2fsiu